# Calling external library from python returns wrong result when specifying result type using ctypes

Tags: python, character-encoding, ctypes

I've got an external C library with a function

```
extern ushort* getSomeStringW(ushort* Dest, int MaxLen);
```

The function changes the `Dest` buffer, and returns it.
I am wrapping it with ctypes. Since the library always returns 16bit encoded strings I have to explicitly use `c_ushort` or `c_uint16` buffers, and can't just create `c_wchar_t` buffers using ctypes `create_unicode_buffer` method. (`c_wchar_t` is 16bit on Win, but 32bit on OSX)

Therefore I call the library like this:

```
dest = (ctypes.c_uint16 * MaxLen)()
result = library.getSomeStringW(byref(dest), MaxLen)
```

This works as expected. Interestingly ctypes seems to guess the return type, and result is a python string. I can also access the contents in the `dest` buffer afterwards, and explicitly decode it as utf-16.

Now I thought about specifying the `restype` of the function nontheless, but weirdly enough the results are wrong after that.

If, instead of the above code, I use

```
dest = (ctypes.c_uint16 * MaxLen)()
library.getSomeStringW.restype = ctypes.c_uint16 * MaxLen
result = library.getSomeStringW(byref(dest), MaxLen)
```

The `result` array looks different from the `dest` array. I know that the arrays probably don't reference the same memory location (at least that's what I make of the ctypes documentation) but I still don't get why the result ctypes object is not filled correctly.

It works when I use the numpy ctypelib and declare the `restype` as

```
import numpy as np

library.getSomeStringW.restype = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ctypes.c_uint16, shape=(MaxLen,))
```

... which confuses me even more.

In the case where it does not work, the `dest` array looks like I would expect

```
0000 = {int} 52
0001 = {int} 46
0002 = {int} 49
0003 = {int} 48
0004 = {int} 46
0005 = {int} 50
0006 = {int} 46
0007 = {int} 50
0008 = {int} 56
0009 = {int} 56
0010 = {int} 53
0011 = {int} 0
0012 = {int} 0
...
1000 = {int} 0
```

while the `result` array looks something like

```
0000 = {int} 53920
0001 = {int} 25850
0002 = {int} 321
0003 = {int} 0
0004 = {int} 63968
0005 = {int} 35350
0006 = {int} 32764
0007 = {int} 0
0008 = {int} 52816
0009 = {int} 47565
0010 = {int} 32764
0011 = {int} 0
0012 = {int} 39040
0013 = {int} 26425
0014 = {int} 321
0015 = {int} 0
...
```

Every 4th integer seems to be 0, the values are all over the place (and obviously not sensible utf-16 character values)

Thanks for any ideas you might have!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that the result array changes every time I run the code, I realized that I am not setting the result to a pointer.

Of course the numpy funtion also creates a pointer.

```
library.getSomeStringW.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint16 * MaxLen)
```

resolves all problems.